# Get the entire contents of an ethereum block with the fewest queries?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ether, web3.py

Currently to get all of the transactions in a block I pull the block with:

`web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber)`

and then I query every transaction in that block:

```
for t in block['transactions]:
    tx = web3.eth.getTransaction
```

This amounts to a large number of requests made to the chain.

Is there a simpler way to just pull the entirety of a block in a request?

Or use fewer requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Developer advocate from Chainstack here

Please give this a try:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber,true)
```

This returns all transaction details with getBlock method.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wuzhong/60fa8rd1/4/)

Wuzhong/Chainstack